# Using git filter-branch to remove everything except one subdirectory

Tags: git, subdirectory

I have been trying to use git to remove everything except the source code in a particular branch. The

```
git filter-branch -f \
    --subdirectory-filter source_code \
    --prune-empty \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

command gets me basically what I want, except it places the files in `source_code/` at the root, whereas I want them all to remain in the directory. I.e.

```
- source_code
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
```

not just

```
- file1.py
- file2.py
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [--tree-filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```sh
git filter-branch \
    --tree-filter "find . -type f -not -wholename './source_code/*' -delete" HEAD
```